# Periodically extract Info from Linkedin

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I am trying to build an app where I want to use the LinkedIn API to pull information of registered members. I want to keep periodically pulling info from LinkedIn to check if there has been any change in their status, like new job, new education.

Question: Is it possible to keep periodically pulling info of LinkedIn accounts once the member has given permission to my app ?